# data storage and retrieval for search

Tags: postgresql

We have a searchable list. Initially the list displayed will be empty. As soon as the user types in 3 characters, it will start hitting the database and fetching data which matches the 3 characters typed in. The list contains names of organizations. The catch is - the data may have "Private" but the user may try Pvt or something like that and end up thinking the data is missing. Which is the best approach to get around this problem? One approach we are considering is to have all possible combinations of the values a user may try in another column, do the look up against that column, and display the column which has the 'clean' data. Any other approaches? Performance is not a big concern because at most we will have 5000 records in the master table. The master data will be queries by the user once or twice for registration.

Comment: Normalize on input using a synonym dictionary?

Comment: The [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) module has what you're looking for. Build a [functional index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-expressional.html) on metaphone, for instance.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Some link/hint on how that is done? We use python and PostgreSQL.

Comment: My comment was in response to Craig's reply. The query gets generated automatically. So I feel working on the input may be easier. An ILIKE query is what gets generated.